# Connector creation throwing org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.RebalanceNeededException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In connector post request creation I am  getting the error below:

```
 Error message : 500 Internal Server Error,
 error response: {"error_code":500,"message":"org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.RebalanceNeededException: Request cannot be completed because a rebalance is expected"}

Requst body:
{"name":"pg_sink_connector_ansv_mc","config":{"name":"pg_sink_connector_ansv_mc","connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","connection.user":"postgres","database.dbname":"ansv_mc","connection.password":"postgres","topics":"ansv_mc.public.discovery_channel_message","transforms":"unwrap","transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState","database.server.name":"ansv_mc","database.port":"5432","auto.create":"true","database.hostname":"pg-common,"connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://pg-common.postgres????????"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a sink connector, which in simple terms is a Kafka consumer which reads records from Kafka and write to postgres.

The Kafka consumer cannot read while the re-balance is in progress (Kafka is assigning the partitions to the consumers in the group). See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988002/what-does-rebalancing-mean-in-apache-kafka-context)

This should be an intermittent problem and sink connector should recover in the following iterations.